# Boolean value automatically set after upload

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-column, yes-no-field, boolean-field

In the version history, we see that one of our site columns (Boolean type) has a value automatically set after uploading (version 0.1 of item). We have tested this using Graph, drag and drop - we got the same results.

This doesn’t happen to any other site column. We use the same solution for different SharePoint Online sites and this field is always left blank.

Why does this column behave differently than any other Boolean column in our solution? Is there a way to change it?

Comment: Are you able to set the blank value for other boolean fields? As per my understanding you can either set Yes or No as default value for boolean field and blank value is not supported.

Comment: I'm not able to set it manually, but I think it is set automatically after upload to SharePoint. For example, when we upload on other environments - in version history, version 0.1 is empty, values are set only in version 0.2. In this one case, it is the only field in version 0.1 that is set to its default value from the content type (Yes), and then changed in version 0.2 with a value provided by us (No).